# Error while installing Egit plugin on JBuilder

Tags: git, egit, jbuilder

excuse me for my english ^^"
I tried to install EGit plugin on JBuilder 2008 R2 but it gave me this error:
Cannot complete the request.  See the details.
  Cannot complete the request.  See the details.
  Cannot find a solution satisfying the following requirements Match[requiredCapability:
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.objectweb.asm/[3.0.0.v200803061811,3.0.0.v200803061811]].

There is a way to solve this error?

Comment: Are there details somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EGit is an Eclipse Team provider for the Git version control system. see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/). So not to be user for JBuilder. Its should be used with Eclipse IDE.

JBuilder Professional edition support only CVS while Enterprise edition support for Bugzilla, subversion, CVS, Apache Continuums, Borland® StarTeam®s and XPlanners. See the feature matrix pdf [here](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/jbuilder)

There is no integrated support for git team provider inside JBuilder. Either you have work with git using command line interface(CLI) or with some external GUI client mentioned [here](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)

Comment: Ok, thanks.
Do you know a good uml plugin for eclipse? Because i need also git integration and uml diagram.

Comment: There are many, search in google or in stackoverflow itself or ask separate question. You can accept this answer(by clicking the Pass Mark button to the left side of the answer) if you feel the answer is correct.

Comment: Ok, excuse me, i'm new in stackoverglow ^^", now i checked your answer as correct ^^"